# parametro de una funcion en python

Tags: python, socket

estoy creando un socket servidor que se mantendra en linea con un cliente para que pueda recibir y enviar mensajes (chat). Lo he intentado de muchas maneras pero no puedo terminarlo por errores de sintaxis (llevo 2 meses aprendiendo).

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import threading
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
serv = sock.bind(('10.0.10.112', 8003))
if serv == None:
        print '[] Servidor en linea []'
sock.listen(2)

conexion, addr = sock.accept()
print str(addr) + ' ha establecido una conexion'

def emision(mensaje):
        mensaje = raw_input(">> ")
        if mensaje == 'salir':
                break
        conexion.send(mensaje)
        return

while True:
        msj = threading.Thread(target=emision, args=(mensaje))
        msj.start()
        peticion = conexion.recv(1024)
        print str(addr) + '[:] ' + peticion
```

Al ejecutar me dice que el mensaje no está definido. Toda correccion y recomendaciones seran bien escuchas.
++PD: lo intente con try-except pero en except no me marca los errores (ej: socket.error, KeyboardInterrupt). Será por que uso Nano para codear?

SALUDOS!!

Answer (score 0):

En `sock = socket.socket()` debes especificar el tipo de conexion que vas a establecer.

sock es desde donde debes trabajar, en tu caso, podrías sustituir sock por serv.

En `serv.bind((10.0.10.112, 8003))` debes poner la ip de la maquina servidor, o localhost si estas trabajando en local. En definitiva, ¿Por que direccion IP y Puerto debo escuchar?
Puedes poner 0.0.0.0 si quieres que escuche de cualquiera de las conexiones que tenga el equipo.

A parte, no logro entender la función de esto: `if serv == None:`

en la parte de la función "emisión" no estas devolviendo nada, por tanto no necesitas un return.

Aquí te muestro el código con esta correcciones. Por favor, la próxima vez copia el error completo también, eso aporta mucha información útil.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import threading
import socket

#Le digo que use IPv4 y TCP
serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
#Que escuche desde cualquier sitio en el puerto 8003
serv = sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8003))
#Escuchar dos conexiones entrantes
serv.listen(2)

#Aceptamos la conexion
conexion, addr = sock.accept()

print str(addr) + ' ha establecido una conexion'

def emision(mensaje): #Solo recibe por parámetro un mensaje y lo envía.
            conexion.send(mensaje)

while True:
        #Mudo esta parte del codigo aqui para salir del programa antes de entrar en la funcion
        mensaje = input(">> ")
        if mensaje == 'salir':
                break
        else:
            msj = threading.Thread(target=emision, args=(mensaje))
            msj.start()

        peticion = conexion.recv(1024)
        print(str(addr) + '[:] ' + peticion)
```

Comment: NameError: name 'salir' is not defined. No sirve la correcion :( gracias de todos modos

Comment: @FrioEspacial ¿Cuando te sale ese error? ¿Al ejecutarlo? ¿Al escribirlo? ¿Que version de python estas usando?